# What adjective describes somebody who is quiet and obeys all the rules?

Tags: single-word-requests

What adjective describes somebody who is quiet and obeys all the rules? For example,

*"Xiaoli is a very (adj.) student because she doesn't smoke or drink, gets good grades, and always does her homework ahead of time"*.

The word that comes to mind is *obedient*, but I think this word has the negative connotation in the way that a servant would "obey" his master. I'm looking for an entirely positive adjective.

A possible antonym to my word might be *wild*, which you might use to describe someone who parties all night, gets drunk, etc.

Comment: You will never find a word that comprises both “doesn’t smoke or drink” and “gets good grades”, because these have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: A possible antonym for *wild* would be *disciplined*, though that does not have as wide-ranging a meaning as you want. Your best option would be "Xiaoli is a **good** girl".

Comment: If you consider "quiet" and "obedient" to be highly desirable characteristics in a student, then (considering them together with the characteristics "vice-free," "diligent," and "punctual") you might be able to sum up the student as  _exemplary_. Not everyone views "quiet" or even "obedient" as unalloyed virtues, however.

Comment: The first word that came to mind was **obsequious**, but that doesn't really fit with your sentence.

Comment: The first word that comes to mind is Pedantic.

Answer (score 9):

You can say she is a very **well-disciplined** student. [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-disciplined) suggests that it has the meaning:

> having been strictly trained or conditioned to ensure good behaviour, orderliness, etc

Or you can simply call her a **model student**.

If you want to describe a righteous person, you can use the word

> **virtuous**
>
> having or showing high moral standards.

or maybe you just want to describe a person *who's quiet and obeys all the rules*, in other words,

> **biddable**
>
> meekly ready to accept and follow instructions.

Comment: There are two kinds of students in this world: *virtual students* — and *real students*. :)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is tricky, because it's entirely possible for a student to live a “wild” lifestyle, yet still turn their homework in on time, and get good grades.  Not all party animals bring home bad grades, and not all stoners fail to turn their homework in on time.

One term that sprang to my mind is ***goody two-shoes*** (although, I'll have to admit, that term is often used pejoratively). Many dictionaries define *goody two-shoes* to be an alternate form of *goody-goody*, which, according to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/goodygoody), is defined as:

> **goody-goody** (*noun*) a smugly virtuous or sanctimonious person

However, at least [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goody-two-shoes) allows for the term to be used in a more positive light:

> **goody two-shoes** (*noun*) a person who is goody-goody; *also* : a person who is uncommonly good

If that doesn't work for you, though, you could use the describe this person as ***scholarly***, or as a ***conscientious student***.

*Scholarly* has a few different meanings, but I think one found in NOAD aligns with your purposes well:

> **scholarly** (*adj*.) having or showing knowledge, learning, or devotion to academic pursuits

I would think that *devoted to academic pursuits*, in particular, might be a fitting description for people like Xiaoli.  *Conscientious* also seems to be an apt word; NOAD defines it as:

> **conscientious** (*adj*.) wishing to do what is right, esp. to do one's work or duty well and thoroughly

I think *conscientious* might be my best suggestion, because it carries connotations of both upright living and careful work habits.  WordNet defines it as:

> **conscientious** (*adj.*) ***1*** guided by or in accordance with conscience or sense of right and wrong
>    ***2*** characterized by extreme care and great effort

I like [Wiktionary's](http://www.wordnik.com/words/conscientious) definition as well:

> **conscientious** (*adj.*) Thorough, careful, or vigilant; implies a desire to do a task well

Answer (score 2):

The judgmental term that replaces "adj" in your sentence is normally *good*. However, the sentence doesn't necessarily describe someone "who is quiet and obeys all the rules", only someone "who doesn't smoke or drink, gets good grades, and always does her homework ahead of time". Some appropriate words might be *compliant, **conscientious**, docile, **dutiful**, **punctilious**, **submissive***.

Answer (score 1):

You might be describing "a **compliant** student"

Please see [Students As Real People: Interpersonal Communication and Education](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=2RpCUDOq2zIC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=compliant+student&source=bl&ots=Omeu5Do_pA&sig=Hsq50FpBSVhEkuXe3UXykdmca8k&hl=tr&sa=X&ei=fuTpUJ3AOMWC4gSY1IDICA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=compliant%20student&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the person you describe is a [*responsible*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/responsible) person:

> **responsible**  *adj*
>   4. Able to make moral or rational decisions on one's own and therefore answerable for one's behavior.
>   5. Able to be trusted or depended upon; reliable.
>   6. Based on or characterized by good judgment or sound thinking: responsible journalism.

Answer (score 0):

For just the last two, the "gets good grades, and always does her homework ahead of time", you could consider the word **studious**. However, that doesn't fit too much with the not smoking and drinking part.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd call that person a  ***strait-laced rule-follower***

> [***strait-laced***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/strait-laced) : *Excessively strict in behavior, morality, or opinions.*

But I also think that @Arch's ***virtuous model-student*** works rather nicely too.