# Word for someone who hates getting in trouble

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word to describe someone who hates getting in trouble?

Comment: You really need to narrow this down a bit.

Comment: Coward. Or if you like Discworld - **Rincewind**.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of either [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241276/what-word-describes-a-person-who-acts-like-a-goody-good-because-they-fear-reperc) or [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102511/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-does-not-take-risks-or-who-does-not-like-taking-r/), depending on what "getting in trouble" is supposed to mean.

Comment: [Another potential duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96889/what-adjective-describes-somebody-who-is-quiet-and-obeys-all-the-rules) for the former sense.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is the expression "[goody two shoes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/goody-two-shoes?q=Goody%20two%20shoes)":

> An ostentatiously virtuous or well-behaved person:
>   'she was such a goody two shoes.'
>   'I don’t drink alcohol. Goody two shoes, that’s me.'

I don't think I've ever seen a single word expression that adequately conveys the same concept.